# The title "URL" in Advanced Search Tips should not be uppercased for localized sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, localization

In the [Advanced Search Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) table the title "URL" is uppercased via css style:

> [image: URL]

HTML sourse looks like this:

```
<th scope="row" class="tt-uppercase">url</th>
```

Such approach is not suitable for localized sites like Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: URL-АДРЕС]

The sub-word "АДРЕС" (means address) should not be uppercased here. Much better way is to manage case sensitivity via translations on Transifex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now:

> [image: new URL]

<sub>(ссылка means "a link")</sub>
Class attribute has been removed from the original HTML source:
`<th scope="row">URL</th>`